# Can an Android app create a local sessions that others using the same app can connect to without a need of an intermediate server?

Tags: java, android, server, local

I am totally new in android development and wanted to create this app that will keep score of a darts game. I want to create a private session and only people with the ID can join, everybody inputs their score every round individually using their own smartphone and the person who created the session is hosting the server and all the calculations and score tracking is hosted on that persons device. Is that possible or is an intermediate server a must?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Wi-Fi Direct for that - it's a P2P network with a "group owner".

Here's the relevant [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/wifi-direct).

Comment: Note that this has a limit of wifi distance-  about 100m max.  Above that it won't work, and you need a server.

Comment: @GabeSechan for the application of a dart game, the range of the radio should suffice... because this is a game commonly being played in a pub (even when it's a crowded pub, the diffusion of the signal should still be acceptable). in such a scenario, one sometimes doesn't even have 3G/4G network coverage.